# Uncrustify keeps adding spaces for aligning braces over and over

Tags: uncrustify

I'm running into issues with my uncrustify cfg: https://gist.github.com/giesberge/14fffc07ece83d2d33907890febfc46e

Where it keeps adding spaces everytime I iterate on it to align these braces

Iteration 0

```
TEST(MatrixTests, MatrixScalarMultiplication_Left) {
    tempMatrix =
    {
        { 2.0,  4.0,  6.0,  8.0,  10.0,  12.0  },
        { 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0, 22.0,  24.0  },
        { -2.0, -4.0, -6.0, -8.0, -10.0, -12.0 }
    };
}
```

Iteration 1

```
TEST(MatrixTests, MatrixScalarMultiplication_Left) {
    tempMatrix =
    {
        { 2.0,  4.0,  6.0,  8.0,  10.0,  12.0   },
        { 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0, 22.0,  24.0   },
        { -2.0, -4.0, -6.0, -8.0, -10.0, -12.0  }
    };
}
```

Iteration 2

```
TEST(MatrixTests, MatrixScalarMultiplication_Left) {
    tempMatrix =
    {
        { 2.0,  4.0,  6.0,  8.0,  10.0,  12.0    },
        { 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0, 22.0,  24.0    },
        { -2.0, -4.0, -6.0, -8.0, -10.0, -12.0   }
    };
}
```

I've played around with a few settings but they don't seem to be working.